# Why is there two Object for a function in the Javascript prototype chain

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at the hierarchy (prototype chain) of the code below and I don't understand where the second (lower Object) comes from. I understand that the "t" variable is the instance of the Object object, but why is there another Object under the first Object? I thought that Object was the final link in the chain. So, I'm confused because this prints test => Object => Object

```
function test (){ }
var t = new test()
console.log(t)
```

[image]

Clarification: Using Chrome browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`t` is an object whose prototype is ***an object*** whose prototype is **Object.prototype**. That is expected; If `t`'s prototype was `Object.prototype` directly then adding properties to `t's` prototype would affect all objects instead of just `t` and other objects created by `new test`. That wouldn't be desirable, hence the intermediate object whose prototype is Object.prototype.

To clarify further: When you declare a function its prototype property is set to a new empty object, and objects, by default, have a prototype of `Object.prototype`.

`t`'s prototype is `test.prototype` and `test.prototype`'s prototype is `Object.prototype`.

Comment: So, the first Object is the test function prototype and then the second is the final Object prototype which test function is based on?

Comment: @user3092075 That's mostly accurate, but note that `test`'s prototype is not the same as `test.prototype` (the property that determines the prototype of objects that are created from `new test`).  `test`'s actually prototype is `Function.prototype`. EG. `Object.getPrototypeOf( test ) === Function.prototype;`, which is not the same as `test.prototype`; `test.prototype` is just an empty object (which has a prototype of Object.prototype).

Comment: @user3092075 close. The first is an object that is serving as `Test.prototype`, second is *that* object's prototype, which is `Object.prototype`.

Comment: Ok, then would it be correct to say then test.prototype == t ? In other words, t is equal to test.prototype

Comment: @user3092075 No, it would be correct to say `Object.getPrototypeOf( t ) === test.prototype`, in other words `t`'s prototype is `test.prototype`. That's part of what the `new` keyword does in JavaScript (it creates an object whose prototype is `constructor.prototype` for some constructor function). In your case the constructor is `test`.

Comment: So why does  `test.prototype == t`  print `false`? Aren't they both referring to the same thing? The thing that `t` is built on, `test.prototype`

Comment: `t` is an object whose prototype is `test.prototype`. That is not the same as saying `t` is `test.prototype`.

Comment: @Paulpro - ok, I understand now. So it's actually t.__proto__ == test.prototype

Comment: @user3092075—the `__proto__` notation was introduced by Mozilla, ECMAScript refers to it as the internal `[[Prototype]]` property to differentiate it from the public *prototype* property, see [*ECMA-262 §9.1 Ordinary Object Internal Methods and Internal Slots*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots).